# Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier or keyword

Tags: angular5

From the schema getting field name and response have value for that field  name

`{{ Response.{{ fieldname }} }}` in angular

getting above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `{{ Response[fieldName] }}` instead. The syntax for accessing a dynamic property is in Typescript is `obj[prop]` where `prop` is a string containing the property's key.

Here is a related question: [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: How to achieve this in typescript
<div *ngFor="let Schema of buttonSchema?.layoutsections">
  <div *ngFor="let Schema1 of Schema?.layoutcolumns">
      <div *ngFor="let Schema2 of Schema1?.layoutItems">
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Sorry, I can't get enough context from your comment to understand the new question. Also, I don't have enough space or formatting tools to fully answer any new questions in the comments. I'd be happy to take a look if you open up a new question and share the link :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303224/how-to-implement-for-loop-concept-for-schemanested